# Wrong search results

Tags: support, search

The picture says everything...

> [image]

Why am I getting accepted answers in the search result? Is it a bug on Stack Overflow?

If not then please suggest me the right query?

Comment: My guess is you're confusing the poor thing by demanding *questions* with less than 5 answers AND *answers* that aren't accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That result is a question (with an accepted answer), not an accepted answer. Try adding `is:answer` if you only want answers.  As pointed out in the comments, your current search requests questions with up to 5 answers (`answers:..5`), but simultaneously requests unaccepted answers (`isaccepted:no`).

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you don't want `isaccepted:no`; you want `hasaccepted:no`. This will get you questions without accepted answers.  I have tested this search:

[`[*eclipse*] votes:10 answers:..5 closed:no hasaccepted:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*eclipse*%5D+votes%3A10+answers%3A..5+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano)

and can verify that it doesn't show any questions with accepted answers.

Comment: No I want to list all questions NOT answers. I tried adding `is:question` BUT still wrong results. Please try and update your post

Comment: Please see my edit; I believe it will address your problem.

Comment: My fault!!! Now working fine..