# Warn the user of incompatible search filters

Tags: feature-request, search

Inspired by this question: [Wrong search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224920/wrong-search-results)

Here the user included "answers:...5" and "isaccepted:no". The first applies to questions, the second to answers. Results were still given, but not what was expected. I can't think of a scenario where someone would want to deliberately include a filter meant for questions and a filter meant for answers.

I think the user should be warned of the incompatible filters when performing the search.

Possibly the notice could even suggest a correction or corrections i.e. for the case above change "isaccepted:no" to "hasaccepted:no", for other cases offer links to searching with the incompatible filters removed.